# How to pass data between components on Different routed pages without putting them on App.js?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass "product" from my Product.js to Cart.js as a prop so that when the user clicks on Add to Cart button the product is transferred to Cart. I use onAdd function on the button to do that(yet to be implemented).

But ı cannot figure out how to pass that prop from Product to Cart without adding those two inside App.js and passing that way. I guess my logic here is suffering from errors. Any help and insight is appreciated. Here is the code;

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hk2sma

Comment: Did you think about using a state management system like Redux or ContextAPI? It will allow you to share data from one local store to any component you want.

Comment: Hey! I am following The Odin Project and yet they have not discussed ContextAPI. So I did not invest time into that! But I know about it. Maybe that is the easiest way to solve this

Comment: The problem with pure React is that you can only pass props from parent component to child component. You cannot pass it the other way around. So, having a local store to which all components are connected would be way easier. More time to set up, but totally worth it especially for bigger scale projects.